# What is a neurometric function?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, decision-making

Is the output of neurometric function the output of the pattern classifier i.e 
is it calculated from processing the imaging data of brain as a prediction of what choice was made through psychometric function?

What confuses me is whether neurometric function is a *neural response* to *pattern classifier response* process or it is a process leading to conversion of *visual stimuli* to *neural response*.

Comment: Can you please add background information about neurometric functions (e.g. where have you seen the term before?) so that readers will have some context to help them understand your question?